# SQL Update : WHERE clause error

Tags: java, sql, sql-update, sqlanywhere

I don't know whats wrong with this query :

```
SQL = "UPDATE "+ choosenClass +" SET COUNT = "+count+" WHERE NAME = "+names;
stmt2.executeUpdate( SQL );
```

Error :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'RAMAYAH' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'RAMAYAH' is not a column in the target table.
```

It says Column RAMAYAH is not there but the string "RAMAYAH" itself is taken from the same table. Help Please.

Comment: can you show more of your code ? what value has choosenClass? how is your table defined ... there are just too many variables in your little shown code

Comment: Btw, without knowing more, this looks like code that could be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should really use prepared statements for this sort of thing, with the SQL looking like `"UPDATE " + chosenClass + " SET count=? WHERE name=?"`. And be sure to check that `chosenClass` only contains the set of characters you'd expect (probably just letters?).

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose the string into single quotes:

```
SQL = "UPDATE "+ choosenClass +" SET COUNT = "+count+" WHERE NAME = '"+names+"'";
stmt2.executeUpdate( SQL );
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `SQL-Injection` vulnerability as mentioned by others in comment; your query has few more mistakes/issues.

You need to quote the filter value in `WHERE` condition `WHERE NAME = "+names` should be
`WHERE NAME = '"+names+"'"`. Otherwise, your query will be formed like below and query engine will presume that there exist a column named `RAMAYAH` in your table in question.

```
UPDATE tab1 SET COUNT = 10 WHERE NAME = RAMAYAH;
```

Also, in your `UPDATE` statement, you have a column names `COUNT` which is a reserve word. You need to escape it to be in safe side.

> If you are using [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) then use backtique
>
> for [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) use `[]` square bracket
>
> for [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) and [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) use `""` double-quote